# Replacement of a line

Tags: text-processing

I have two files namely file1 and file2.
I need to replace 16th line of file2 with 10th line of file1

Answer (score 1):

Use **sed** (stream editor):

```
sed '16 s/.*/'"$(sed -n '10p' file1)"'/' file2
```